# Salesforce UserInfo session type in APEX

Tags: authentication, salesforce, apex, userinfo

I would like to know if there is a way to find out in APEX when an particular user is logged in directly or via the "Login As" feature from the organization's user list.
The UserInfo class doesn't seem to provide any methods for this purpose and i need to know this in my apex code.

thanks in advance

Comment: What is your case? What for you need to know such info?

Comment: I'm developing an 3rd party application used in SFDC and that app calls our web services in the current user's context. I want to prevent the System admin (or whoever is granted to login as someone else) to call our web service when logged in this way.This is a security issue for our web service.

Comment: Sysadmin might have legitimate need to try it out, debug connectivity issues on user's request. "Login as" entries are recorded in Setup Audit Trail but I doubt you can access it... Ask SF support for help? Maybe you shouldn't store credentials then, force users to authenticate against your service every time.

Comment: Yes i don't doubt the admin has to look into other's account, but still he shouldn't be able to see the data from our service. We've contacted SFDC's support about this issue, waiting for some reply.

Answer (score 1):

Something is tracking that your session previously belonged to another user so that the "Logged in as XYZ (foo@bar.com)" message can be displayed in the Salesforce UI.

I suspect this would be cookie based. If this is the case, you could try and isolate it by tracking the cookie changes when you login as another user. If you can find it then you can check for the presence of this cookie in Apex using

```
Cookie counter = ApexPages.currentPage().getCookies().get('loginAsCookieHere');
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this isn't possible with salesforce.